# TensorFlow JS Unhandled Promise Rejection: TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, react-native, tensorflow

I'm trying to detect body poses by passing in an image. The error occurs when create Detector method is called by passing in the model. Tried my best to resolve dependency issues but they are not going away. Tried all methods but nothing is working. Any Help?

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button, Image } from 'react-native'
import sample from './assets/sample.jpg'
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs'
import * as poseDetection from '@tensorflow-models/pose-detection'
import '@tensorflow/tfjs-react-native'

const App = () => {
  const [isTfReady, setTFReady] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    const getTF = async () => {
      tf.ready().then(setTFReady(true))
    }
    getTF()
  })

  const detect = async () => {
    const model = poseDetection.SupportedModels.MoveNet;
    const modelType = poseDetection.movenet.modelType.SINGLEPOSE_LIGHTNING;
    const detector = await poseDetection.createDetector(poseDetection.SupportedModels.MoveNet, { modelType: poseDetection.movenet.modelType.SINGLEPOSE_THUNDER });
    const poses = await detector.estimatePoses(sample);

  }
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Image source={sample} style={{ height: '30%', width: '80%' }}></Image>
      <Text>TFJS ready? {isTfReady ? <Text>Yes</Text> : ''}</Text>
      <Button title='Detect' onPress={detect}></Button>
    </View>
  )
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  }
})
export default App
```

Package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@mediapipe/pose": "^0.5.1675469404",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.17.11",
    "@tensorflow-models/pose-detection": "^2.0.0",
    "@tensorflow/tfjs": "^4.2.0",
    "@tensorflow/tfjs-react-native": "^0.8.0",
    "expo": "~48.0.6",
    "expo-camera": "~13.2.1",
    "expo-file-system": "~15.2.2",
    "expo-gl": "^11.4.0",
    "expo-gl-cpp": "^11.4.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.4",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.3"
  },
```

Error Log

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not a function]
at node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-core\dist\tf-core.node.js:null in decodeString
at node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-core\dist\tf-core.node.js:null in <global>
at node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-core\dist\tf-core.node.js:null in <global>
at node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-core\dist\tf-core.node.js:null in decodeWeights
at node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-converter\dist\tf-converter.node.js:null in GraphModel.prototype.loadSync
at node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-converter\dist\tf-converter.node.js:null in GraphModel.prototype.load
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:null in _allocateCallback$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:null in _callTimer
- ... 8 more stack frames from framework internals
```